# Parsing Multiple Fields to Single Color Vector in Python

Tags: python, parsing, 3d

Is there a good pattern in Python to use for parsing multiple lines of an input file into a single value? For example, I've got an input file that looks something like:

```
BackgroundColor_R=0.0
BackgroundColor_G=0.0
BackgroundColor_B=0.0
BackgroundColor_A=0.0
DensityCorrection_Color_R=1.0
DensityCorrection_Color_G=1.0
DensityCorrection_Color_B=1.0
```

The idea is to get BackgroundColor into a single color vector object as well as DensityCorrection but they are of different sizes and I've like to avoid special logic for each parameter. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your data has two natural representations, one based on the structure of the config file and one based on the usage within the program. In the spirit of [PEP 20 (the Zen of Python)](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/) the conversion from one form to another should be explicit.

```
BackgroundColor = (float(config['BackgroundColor_R']),
                   float(config['BackgroundColor_G']),
                   float(config['BackgroundColor_B']),
                   float(config['BackgroundColor_A']))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can parse such file with ini file parser. http://docs.python.org/library/configparser.html.

But data structures is up to you. It depends on your needs.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work (but using configparser would be better for the first bit):

```
data = {}

for l in open('input').readlines():
    key, value = l.split("=")
    vector_name = key.split("_")[0]
    vector = data.get(vector_name,[])
    vector.append(value)
    data[vector_name] = vector

print data
```